# Origin of "half a mind" and "a piece of my mind"

Tags: expressions

Both of these expressions/phrases have similar uses:

I have *half a mind* to confront that person.

I'm going to give them *a piece of my mind*.

Were these separate but similar expressions translated from non-English phrases and became part of our vernacular or were these sayings "invented" by English speakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom "half a mind" was first used in George Shelvocke's *[A Voyage Around the World](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Voyage_Round_the_World_by_Way_of_the_G.html?id=SGDQAAAAMAAJ)* in 1726:

> They had half a mind to refuse me a passage. (462)

"A piece of my mind" was first used in an English [letter](http://books.google.com/books?id=Bi87AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=%22Thus%20am%20I%20bolde%20to%20unfolde%20a%20peece%20of%20my%20mynde%22&source=bl&ots=O8eSKMH3gE&sig=G4lBzKLZ4JkKYeHmrq7YgHSZ3Xw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M_d7U8moO9iSqAaZj4HgBQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Thus%20am%20I%20bolde%20to%20unfolde%20a%20peece%20of%20my%20mynde%22&f=false) in 1572:

> Thus am I bolde to unfolde a peece of my mynde.